# Encontrar variables en un documento

Tags: javascript

```js
var a1 = setTimeout(function(){});
var a2 = setTimeout(function(){});
var a3 = setTimeout(function(){});
var a4 = setTimeout(function(){});
var a5 = setTimeout(function(){});

if(){
clearInterval(a1);
clearInterval(a2);
// etc..
}
```

*Si tuviera en un código **muchos** `setTimeout`, y cada uno de estos comienza con una variable llamada `"a" + un número`, **como podría identificar todas las variables que empiezan con** a y luego con un número, **para así meterlas a un array** y **recorrerlas para aplicar** el `clearInterval`, **en vez** de estar haciendo el `clearInterval` a cada uno de ellas (imaginando que hay más de 50 variables sería muy tedioso).*

Comment: Pues meterlas en el array se hace y listo `var myArray = [a1,a2,a3..,aN]` pero cómo sería el contexto de una aplicación que requiera de este tipo de funcionalidad?, yo en lo personal siempre evito los timeout por lo mismo que no se puede llevar el control total de estos.

Comment: y envéz de timeout, que usas?

Comment: Depende ahí de para que uses el timeout, yo cuando uso ajax y ocupo hacer una acción al terminar la ejecución uso diferidos en ves de tiemouts

Comment: @Lixus programando juegos en JS+ canvas los timeouts para realizar animaciones son bastante necesarios

Comment: @PabloLozano, lo que sí tengo entendido que es mejor usar requestAnimationFrame que setInterval

Comment: En realidad me refería a encadenar animaciones: un evento que anima algo y al segundo empieza una segunda animación, por ejemplo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con la funcion `Object.keys(window)` puedes obtener todos los objetos.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script>
  var a1 =  setInterval(function(){console.log("txt1");},1000);
  var a2 =  setInterval(function(){console.log("txt2");},1000);
  var a3 =  setInterval(function(){console.log("txt3");},1000);
  var a4 =  setInterval(function(){console.log("txt4");},1000);
  var a5 =  setInterval(function(){console.log("txt5");},1000);

  function detenerObjetosInterval(){
            //obteniendo objetos
   var objetosTodos=Object.keys(window);
   var objetosInterval=[];
   //obteniendo objetos que inicia con 'a'
   for(i = 0 ; i < objetosTodos.length ; i++){
    if(objetosTodos[i].indexOf('a')==0){
     objetosInterval.push(objetosTodos[i]);
    }
   }
   //deteniendo objetos
   for(i = 0 ; i < objetosInterval.length ; i++){
    clearInterval(eval(objetosInterval[i]));
   }
  }
  
  //detener intervals despues de 5 seg
  setTimeout(function(){
   console.log("deteniendo intervals");
   detenerObjetosInterval();
  },5000);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Te recomiendo que los var inicien con una palabra mas compuesta (ejem *var aInterval = ....*), porque si usas librerias u otras cosas podrias coger otros objetos

Comment: Porque usas eval en el clearInterval?

Comment: para que lo reconosca como funcion, de lo contrario lo tomaria como un texto y no ejecutaria

Comment: Ah gracias juliocpiro

Answer (score 13):

En general, cualquier variable global declarada es un atributo del objeto `window`:

```js
var a1 = 5;
var a2 = 6;
var a3 = 'hola';

let i = 1;

while(window['a' + i]) {
  console.log('La variable a' + i + ' vale ' + window['a' + i]);
  i++;
}
```

Pero esto no funciona con variables locales incluso cuando el contexto es `window`:

```js
(function () {
  var a1 = 5
  var a2 = 6
  var a3 = 'hola'

  let i = 1;

  while(window['a' + i]) {
    console.log('La variable a' + i + ' vale ' + window['a' + i]);
    i++;
  }
  
  console.log('El contexto es: ', this.toString());
})()
```

Mi recomendación es guardar los valores directamente en un array:

```js
let timeouts = [];

for (let i = 0;i < 5; i++) {
  timeouts.push(setTimeout(() => console.log('Hola ' + i), i * 2000));
  // Al usar let en lugar de var, cada callback tiene un valor distinto para i ;)
}

setTimeout(() => {
  timeouts.forEach(id => clearTimeout(id));
//clearTimeout en el caso presente, no clearInterval
  console.log('Eliminados los timeouts no ejecutados');
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Si señor. Has dado en el clavo. Solo iteras por los miembros de `window` que nos interesan, y paras en el primer *no encontrado*. Obra de arte :-)

Comment: En la prueba veo que se ejecutan sólo 2 timeouts y no 5... Sale: `Hola 0, Hola 1, Eliminados los timeouts no ejecutados` ¿me perdí algo?

Comment: @A.Cedano Se trata de eso: hay 5 timeouts, pero en algún momento antes de que todos se hayan ejecutado queremos cancelar las ejecuciones pendientes

Comment: Al usar let solucionas el scope, no?

Comment: Exacto, con var todos los timeouts mostrarían 5

Comment: @Trauma Si hay un solo intervalo llamado `a15`, falla.

Comment: @ArtEze Si, claro, falla porque no encuentra `a1` y aborta la búsqueda. Pero, según el ejemplo del OP, es *perfecta*. `letra` + `números enteros consecutivos empezando por el 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría lo siguiente: crearía un arreglo con los nombres de todas las posibles variables, luego lo recorrería con `forEach` comprobaría si el objeto `window` posee una *"propiedad"* llamada como la variable en el arreglo, si es así, hago lo que tenga que hacer con dicha variable, si no, muestro un error diciendo que dicha variable no existe, ejemplo:

```js
var a1 = setTimeout(() => {});
var a2 = setTimeout(() => {});
var a3 = setTimeout(() => {});
var a4 = setTimeout(() => {});
var a5 = setTimeout(() => {});

const possibleVariablesNum = 10;
var possibleVariablesArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i <= possibleVariablesNum; i++){
  possibleVariablesArr.push("a" + i.toString());
}

possibleVariablesArr.forEach((value, index) => {
  if (window.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
    console.log("La variable " + value + " existe y se limpiará");
    clearInterval(window[value]);
  }else{
    console.error("La variable " + value + " NO existe");
  }
})
```

Comment: Es aún peor, imaginate si tengo 100 variables

Comment: @EduardoSebastian sinceramente no hay otra forma, al menos que yo conozca para realizar lo que deseas...

Comment: @EduardoSebastian edité mi respuesta, quizá así no lo veas tan engorroso

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guardar los identificadores de `setTimeout` y `setInterval` en un objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
let itervals = {
    a1: setInterval(()=>{}, 100),
    a2: setInterval(()=>{}, 100),
    a3: setInterval(()=>{}, 100)
}
```

Luego, puedes recorrer el objecto:

```
for(let i in intervals){
    clearInterval(intervals[i]);
}
```

Propongo utilizar un objeto porque en tu código están las variables declaradas, pero puedes utilizar también un `Array` simple:

```
let intervals = [
    setInterval(()=>{}, 100),
    setInterval(()=>{}, 100),
    setInterval(()=>{}, 100),
]

for(let i in intervals){
    clearInterval(intervals[i]);
}
```